# Using different VkDevice for image and its view

Tags: vulkan

It would appear that it is possible to create `VkImage` and `VkImageView` with different `VkDevice` (I couldn't find spec saying otherwise). What is the relation of `VkDevice` to these objects in this case? Does it make possible to read/write data from one device to other with a shader? `vkCmdBindDescriptorSets()` says `Each of commandBuffer, layout, and the elements of pDescriptorSets must have been created, allocated, or retrieved from the same VkDevice`, but does it mean `VkDescriptorSet` themselves, or the resources which they bind?

Besides that, it seems possible to `vkUpdateDescriptorSets()` with a different device than from which the descriptor sets were allocated. In this case I don't see how choosing a device affects anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot mix objects. At best you can import\export stuff with `VK_KHR_external_memory_*`.

`vkUpdateDescriptorSets()` common parent VU is just messy because it is generated by an imperfect script.

Comment: What is 'common parent VU'?

Comment: @user369070 That is just how the type of the VU is named. E.g. `VUID-vkQueueSubmit-commonparent`.